# Visual Basic Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to determine if a cell is greater than 0 and I keep getting a Run time error type mismatch, and when I click log it shows me this line is incorrect:

```
 If Cells(13, "U").value > 0 Then
```

Just trying to check if that cell is greater than 0.

Comment: My guess is that the value in that cell is either a text string or an error.

Comment: Sorry...moment of madness! That is a sign that it is time for bed.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to make sure the worksheet is right. jcrizk gives good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

Cast to double:

```
If CDbl(Cells(13, "U").value) > 0 Then
```

Cast to Long

```
If CLng(Cells(13, "U").value) > 0 Then
```

More info available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-conversion-functions).

Also, for future reference, I believe that referencing the sheet that contains the range you're referencing the value in is good practice. In other words:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet name here")
'or this one if working with numbers is more advantageous for you
'Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_index)

If CDbl(ws.Cells(13, "U").Value) > 0 Then
```

Comment: amazing stuff u rock homie